is there a flutter /dart function for getting byte array from live video recording?
We are trying to develop a flutter mobile app(ios and android) and we are looking for a library in flutter that allows me to get access to mobile audio and video frames from device camera and microphone whilst the mobile phone camera is recording as against the traditional process of getting access to the recorded media file only when recording is completed/stopped.
Just to add a bit of context, we would like to mention that we already tried this successfully in the past in HTML/JS using HTML media recorder  However, we recently tried to do this using flutter  because we wanted a native iOS/android app implementation including having access to mobile app features that would be only achievable use native mobile app programming languages like flutter/dart.
So far, we have tried the following flutter libraries:

Flutter camera library: this only has an implementation that allows me takes frames of images using _cameraController.startImageStream((image) => //image frame usage... ));. Can't use this as no audio is included.

Flutter media recorder library this only works for flutter web and cannot be installed a mobile app device as import 'dart:html' as html; keeps throwing some errors.


Note: we have thought of using Flutter media recorder library in a flutter webview widget to enable us install it as a mobile app but we are not sure how this would provide seamless access to audio and video frames in probably byte format, without any over-heads.
Thanks in advance for your responses.

Have you tried using camera package combined with other package that allows audio streaming like https://pub.dev/packages/record ? You can combine this data in flutter

Thank you @MaciejBastian, let me have a look at the Record library and revert soonest.
